# What is the timezone for shkoder, albania in php?

Tags: php, timezone

I need to set the time zone for shkoder, albania country in php language

What is the timezone for shkoder, albania in php?

Comment: Timezone in php for what? o_O

Comment: [Here's a good reference for determining which time zone to use.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (Yes, it's `Europe/Tirane` in this case)

Answer (score 3):

in php code you can do it like

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tirane');
```

Time zones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Docs for setting time zone: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do what anyone else would and look on the PHP website?

```
Europe/Tirane
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php